# Google map slightly moves after scrolling max zoom or min zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have simple web application where I'm using google maps with javascript. I have set min and max zoom level in map like this:  `this.map.setOptions({ minZoom:3,maxZoom: 17 });` What I'm observing is after scroll i.e either zoom in or zoom out and reaching max or min zoom level ,map slightly moves/slides instead of stopping further zoom in or zoom out. Previously it was working fine.Why this change occurred ? Is there any way to stop map movement after reaching max or min zoom level? this is how i'm loading map to div.

```
 self.map = new gmaps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {         mapTypeControlOptions: {
                position: gmaps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
                style: gmaps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
            },
            fullscreenControl: false,
            backgroundColor: '#F7F7F7',
            clickableIcons: false,
            streetViewControl: false
        });
```

Zoom events are not handled in my code.After setting min and max zoom level then ,issue can be reproduced on mouse scroll. I observed this issue yesterday only.

Comment: 2 things; 1) please...can you post a self-contained piece of code that will help fellow coders to reproduce the issue and 2) when did you realize that this behavior changed? Also is this behavior consistent across platforms / OSs?

Comment: Thank you. You need to add the code in the body of the question you asked and not as a comment, please, because it makes reading code hard. It should be code that you post and that enables other people where the issue is. Can you also post the VIEW and the code that you use to call the API?

Comment: It might be related to the new tile render launch that was announced in the new [experimental version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases) 3.32 of Maps JavaScript API. If you prefer old render you can temporary switch back using v=3 parameter and loading the [release version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions).
 This workaround will work for 3 month.

Comment: @xomena Thanks,you are right. Downgrading maps to v3.30 solves the problem.Why this workaround is applicable for 3 month only?

Comment: Because Google has a 3 month versioning cycle. In May they will release new version and version 3.30 will be deleted. Have a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions for more details.

Comment: @xomena Got it. Thanks for update and helping me.

Comment: @Omar I am using require js to load script and 'gmaps' is simply name for that module. Using this 'gmaps' I'm doing all map related operations. Mistakenly I putted new google.maps.Map in comment so correcting it. Anyway, Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest updating your code so that you can avoid issues like these in the future. Using the latest object names will help you avoid [errors and/or warnings](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#checking-errors) (like these) due to deprecation. As suggested by @Xomena, you may stay up-to-date with the `experimental` and `release` versions [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions).

However, I suggest getting ahead of the curve by updating the `Google MapOptions` object property names being called on by your code. Review the code sample below, you'll see that in [Maps JS API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-positioning), the prefix `google.maps` for the `Map Type control` style property options is used; note that is is NOT `gmaps.MapTypeControlStyle`. Little updates like these help you stay ahead of future release versions.

> The Map Type control may appear in one of the following style options:
>
> > `google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR` displays the array of controls as buttons in a horizontal bar as is shown on Google Maps.
> >     `google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU` displays a single button control allowing you to select the map type via a dropdown menu.
> >     `google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT` displays the default behavior, which depends on screen size and may change in future versions of the API.

```
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: {lat: -28.643387, lng: 153.612224},
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
      },
      zoomControl: true,
      zoomControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
      },
      scaleControl: true,
      streetViewControl: true,
      streetViewControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
      },
      fullscreenControl: true
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
```